# Client doesn't recognize end of file stream

Tags: java, file-transfer, bufferedinputstream, bufferedoutputstream

I'm making File Transfer Thread with java

Here is **Server's Code**

```
(fileWriter = new BufferedOutputStream(fileTransferSocket.getOutputStream()))

        try {
            BufferedInputStream fileReader = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(CLIENT_PATH + "/" + filename));

            int packet;

            while((packet = fileReader.read()) != -1)
                fileWriter.write(packet);

            fileWriter.flush();
            fileReader.close();

            System.out.println(filename + " send complete");
        }
```

And **Client's Code**

```
(fileReader = new BufferedInputStream(fileTransferSocket.getInputStream()))

            try {
                BufferedOutputStream fileWriter = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(PROGRAM_PATH + "/" + filename)));

                int packet;

                while((packet = fileReader.read()) != -1)
                    fileWriter.write(packet);

                System.out.println(filename + " receive complete.");
                fileWriter.close();
            }
```

Server Prints

```
    System.out.println(filename + " send complete");
```

It means Server send every bytes of file.

However, Client doesn't print

```
System.out.println(filename + " receive complete.");
```

I checked how many times while loop runs(Checked Both, server and client)

Both while loops runs 685 times

I think Client's while loop doesn't recognize end of file transfer.

Anyone knows problem?

Answer (score 1):

To send `EOF` to the socket, close `fileWriter` at the server.

```
while((packet = fileReader.read()) != -1)
   fileWriter.write(packet);

fileWriter.close(); // note
fileReader.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can test print -1 in your service to tell the end of the transform :

```
while((packet = fileReader.read()) != -1)
            fileWriter.write(packet);
fileWriter.write(-1);
```

Comment: It doens't work either... I cannot escape while loop.

Comment: This is not right. Sending -1 just sends the byte value `0xFF`. -1 is returned specially by an input stream `read` method, it is not part of the stream itself.

Comment: It seems that in basic input or output stream the byte is from 0-255 ,so in data transform level you can not tell the client that is end.Otherwise you close the socket or use the application logic data replace the end , not only the -1 in client.It may be some special characters.